# How can I return only part of my grep result?

Tags: shell-script, sed, grep

Currently I have the current command in my script:

```
udevadm info /dev/nvme0n1 | grep P:
```

In order to return the following information :

```
P: /(PCIe address)/nvme0/nvme0n1/
```

Essentially I dont want the nvme namespace to be part of the of the grep, only the PCIe address, I have seen similar things done with sed however even after reading it doesnt seem to be the most intuitive, so would rather use grep if I could.
Thanks

Comment: Since standard `grep` only returns complete lines, it would be good to know what `grep` you are using (i.e. GNU `grep` on Linux) to know whether answers may rely on non-standard features.

Comment: can't you just do `udevadm info -q path /dev/nvme0n1`?

Comment: nope doesnt return just the pcie address

Comment: Thanks that seems to work great... thats helped me out a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `sed` does not need to be very complicated.

The following `sed` command discards all lines that do not start with the string `P:` (the 1st expression), it then deletes everything up to the first `/` (the 2nd expression), and everything from the `/nvme0/nvme0n1/` to the end of the line in the modified line (the 3rd expression).  These operations should leave the PCIe address.

```bsh
udevadm info /dev/nvme0n1 |
sed -e '/^P:/!d' \
    -e 's,[^/]*/,,' \
    -e 's,/nvme0/nvme0n1/.*,,'
```

Or, as Stéphane points out [in comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/671686/how-can-i-return-only-part-of-my-grep-result/671687#comment1266965_671686),

```bsh
udevadm info -q path /dev/nvme0n1
```

Comment: unfortunately udevadm info -q path /dev/nvme0n1 still returns the returns the namespace.... all im after is the pcie address

Comment: @Earthwormben Since I don't know exactly what you want, could you please update the question with the string that you are searching for? Currently, the question just assumes that we know what a PCIe address looks like, but I can't tell the difference between a PCIe address with and without a namespace.  Also note that I'm not on a system where I can test this `udevadm` command of yours. In fact, I don't know what Unix you are running at all.

Comment: I'm going to read up on sed tomorrow. Whilst a comment above using grep has helped me and is rather simple, my code is rather disorganised now. I believe both my code and my skills will benefit from learning sed.